# Markers drift when zooming (not a custom marker)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I am having marker drifting problems and it doesn't appear to be related to the anchor point of a custom marker. The markers (not custom) drift significantly when it zooms (see pics below)

[image: point at zoom 1]

[image: point at zoom 2]

[image: point at zoom 3]

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsonObjects[i].lat), parseFloat(jsonObjects[i].lon));
 for (var i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {
    var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "norm",
    });
 }
```

**Here is a link to the live code:** http://www.carolinerecord.com/soundMap/soundMapStart.html

Here are some examples of the coordinates I am using:

-79.9025 40.445166

-80.012741 40.445073

-79.94909 40.437257

Comment: Can you link to the page exhibiting the problem?

Comment: What are the coordinates of the marker(s) exhibiting the problem?  Please provide enough code to replicate the issue. The code you did post looks wrong.  What is myLatlng?  Where does it come from (one would assume jsonObjects, but that code isn't provided).

Comment: I added a link with the live code! Note: that they become custom markers when you click on them. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the anchor for a icon the starting-point(0,0) is the top-left corner of the image.

You've set the size of the Icon to `(20, 32)`, and the anchor to `(0,16)`

When you wan't the anchor to be at the bottom-center of the Icon, the anchor must be set to `(halfOfImageWidth,ImageHeight)`

so in your case it has to be:

```
anchor:new google.maps.Point(10,32)
```

But however, you may ommit the `anchor`-property, the API will set the anchor per default to the bottom-center.

Comment: I will try this shortly. But why does the problem persist with non custom markers (as are shown on the live example)?

Comment: The position of the markers is correct, the positions of the map-tiles are wrong. The wrong position is forced by this format, defined for `img` : `left: -50%;`

Comment: It was that css. I didn't realize that tag would apply to even the standard google map marker. Thank you.